# Render filter component in a dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying render filter(s) in a `mat-dialog`, I came to a point where it is rendered correctly, but functionally not usable and I'm not sure if this is the right way or not.

here is the code

here is how I create and open the dialog:

```js
  public lol(colDef: ColDef): void {
    console.log(colDef);

    this.gridApi?.getFilterInstance(colDef.field, (foo) => {
      console.log(foo.getModel());
      foo.setModel(foo.getModel());

      this.dialog.open(FilterWrapperDialogComponent, {
        data: {
          filterHtml: foo.getGui()
        },
        panelClass: 'ag-custom-component-popup'
      }).afterClosed().subscribe((applyOrNot) => {
        if (applyOrNot) {
          this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
          console.log(foo.getModel());
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

the dialog content:

```html
<mat-dialog-content>
  <div class="ag-theme-material ag-custom-component-popup" [innerHTML]="data.filterHtml?.innerHTML | safeUrl: 'html' "></div>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-raised-button i18n [mat-dialog-close]="true" color="primary">Apply</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

it renders correctly, but it looses functionality.

My goal is to set a filter without actually adding to the ag-grid table, just through a dialog and ag-grid API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `[innerHTML]="data.filterHtml?.innerHTML | safeUrl: 'html' "` which strips any functionality for safety reasons ( XSS ).
The solutions was to give an id to the div and append the html from `getGui()`

Dialog HTML:

```html
<mat-dialog-content>
  <div class="ag-theme-material ag-custom-component-popup" id="second"></div>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
<button mat-raised-button i18n [mat-dialog-close]="true" color="primary">Apply</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Appending HTML to the div; dialog logic:

```js
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Inject, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter-wrapper-dialog',
  templateUrl: './filter-wrapper-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter-wrapper-dialog.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class FilterWrapperDialogComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    document.querySelector('#second').appendChild((this.data.filterHtml as HTMLElement));
  }

}
```

With these changes I was able to render the filter correctly and functionally.